# Are the outputs of layers in Attention Is All You Need interpretable by mapping to tokens?

Tags: transformer, attention

In the basic transformer model from 2017, I'm a bit confused what the outputs of each layer are supposed to be. Are they embeddings? If so, does that mean you could examine a given output from a given encoder and decoder layer and covert it to tokens basically? In other words, for a given layer output, suppose you used a similarity search over the token embeddings for the entire vocabulary, and then matched the most similar words to the embeddings from the chosen layer. Would this give you some sense of what words it was basically considering at that point in the architecture?